# Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'. en Android Studio 7.2.2, En zendesk Talk SDK

Tags: android

Este es el codigo, en el cual se trata de hacer la integración con el "TALK SDK" de Zendesk, pero el error que marca al momento de ejecutar la aplicación es este:

"Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'."

*Nota: los datos que aparecen como "..." son datos personales de la empresa.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
ImageButton imgbtn_call;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Zendesk.INSTANCE.init(
            this,
            "https://imm....zendesk.com",
            "c09538565946...",
            "mobile_sdk_client_d9d..."
    );

    Identity identity = new AnonymousIdentity.Builder()
            .withEmailIdentifier("optional user email")
            .withNameIdentifier("optional user name")
            .build();
    Zendesk.INSTANCE.setIdentity(new AnonymousIdentity());

    Talk talk = Talk.create(Zendesk.INSTANCE);

    TalkListenableFuture<LineStatusResult> job = TalkJavaCompat.lineStatus(talk, "digital line test 1");
    job.addListener(new TalkJavaCompatListener<LineStatusResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(@NonNull LineStatusResult result) {
            if(result instanceof LineStatusResult.Success) {
                LineStatusResult.Success success = (LineStatusResult.Success) result;
                if(success.getAgentAvailable()) {
                    imgbtn_call.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    imgbtn_call.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            } else {
                imgbtn_call.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull Throwable throwable) {
            // error occurred when executing lineStatus
        }
    });

    talk.startCallSetupFlow(this, "digital ...", null);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imgbtn_call = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_call);

    imgbtn_call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"LLAMANDO...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: En teoría el problema está en los archivos **build.gradle**. Comparte el error más completo y el contenido de esos archivos.

Comment: Te recomiendo ir **File > Invalidate Caches...** y asi limpiar el cache.